# Network monitor applications mac os x

Tags: networking, mac-osx

I'm trying to pin point what applications are using up my network connection.  Is there an app/widget out there that can show me this?

I'm aware of net monitor but that doesn't seem to tell me what apps are using what traffic.

Ideally what i'd like to see is a bar chart of app usage of net traffic over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ntop - http://www.ntop.org/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

for monitoring bandwidth and traffic usually I use ProteMac Meter ( www.protemac.com )